# FactoryGirl disable linting for some factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have this piece of code in my rails_helper

```
config.before(:suite) do
    begin
      FactoryGirl.lint
  end
```

Which is causing me headaches. I have a User class which can have several attached profiles like this :

```
class User
  has_one :student_profile, class_name: Student
  has_one :employee_profile, class_name: Employee
end
```

Now the thing is, during User registration, I need to send a different email layout depending on which type of user is registering (I am classifying their profiles, and depending on the "stronger" profile, I switch to an appropriate layout.

I have overriden the devise mailer to add a layout based on the main_profile type

```
def layout_for_user(user)
    case user.main_profile // user.employee_profile || user.student_profile || user
    when Employee
      'layouts/mailer/company'
    when Student
      'layouts/mailer/student'
    else
      fail ArgumentError, 'Unknown layout for profile'
    end
end
```

In my registration process, I make sure I build at least one profile type before saving the user/sending the confirmation.

But it would seem that Factory Girl tries to build & save every type of factory, so I am getting lots of `user - Unknown layout for profile (ArgumentError)`

Is there a way to tell FactoryGirl.lint to skip some factories ? It doesn't make sense to have a User without any profile for example, but then an error is still generated

```
# rspec/factories/user.eb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    ...

  trait(:student) do

    after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
      user.student_profile = build(:student_profile,
        user: user)
      end
    end

  factory :student_user, traits: [:student]
end
```

Here my `user` factory is some sort of abstract factory that should never be instanciated alone (otherwise it causes the error explained above) any way to solve that ? I am thinking of commenting this line `FactoryGirl.lint` otherwise ?

Comment: I prefer to skip the linter and do a test in the beginning of each model_spec.
Otherwise you can skip certain models by reading the documentation https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to run `lint` with default arguments. To disable linting for some - factories can be filtered beforehand:

```
FactoryGirl.lint(FactoryGirl.factories.reject{|f| f.name == :some_abstract_factory })
```

Answer (score 2):

if your factory doesn't ever need to be persisted, you can [customize your factory's way to persist the object](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/v4.8.0/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-methods-to-persist-objects):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    to_create { true } # no-op

    # ...
```

this will allow the lint step to succeed, with the caveat that it no longer invokes `save!` when you do `FactoryGirl.create(:foo)`.